# C++ how to detect eof using getline()

Tags: c++

There are some variations of this question but none exactly matches what I'm looking for.

Giving the following code:

```
string command="";

while (command.compare("quit")!=0)
{
    os << prompt;
    getline(is,command);
}
```

How may I detect if `getline` reached eof (end of file)

Comment: You should avoid the attempt to use eof()  in the loop because of this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: looking as *is* flags

Comment: better yet, just check if `is == false`

Comment: @drescherjm what do you mean? I want to exit the loop when I reach the end of file

Answer (score 5):

`getline` returns a reference to the stream you pass to it, and that stream will evaluate to `false` if it hits a failure state.  Knowing that, you can leverage that to move `getline` into the condition for the while loop so that if it fails, then the condition will be false and the loop stops.  You can combine that will your check for `quit` as well like

```
while (getline(is,command) && command != "quit")
{
    // stuff
}
```

---

You can also add the prompt to the loop like

```
while (os << prompt && getline(is,command) && command != "quit")
```

Comment: to be compatible to the OP code : `while (os << prompt, getline(is,command) && command != "quit") {}` ;-)

Comment: @bruno Good idea.  I used `&&` instead of `,` just to keep it consistent.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (command.compare("quit")!=0)
{
    os << prompt;
    getline(is,command);
    if (is.eof())
         do something at end of file
}
```

But note that is reaching end of file does not mean that there isn't something in `command`. You can read data and reach the end of file at the same time.

What you might be looking for instead is this

```
os << prompt;
while (getline(is,command) && command != "quit")
{
    do something with command
    os << prompt;
}
```

That code will quit the loop if you reach end of file and nothing has been input, or if 'quit' is input.

Comment: How may I save what getline returns in a variable so I can pass it to another function?

Comment: @daniel *getline* returns *is* so you already have it

Comment: @daniel getline always returns a reference to the stream that was passed to it (`is` in this case).

Comment: `os << prompt`must be made each turn, so `while (os << prompt, getline(is,command) && command != "quit") ...`

Comment: I mean what is the variable type int string etc?

Comment: The type is `std::istream&`.